Ubuntu Cloud Image terminal display resolution
I've been testing out the Cloud Image variants of Ubuntu Server on a Proxmox VE, but I encounter one issue with the NoVNC console - the resolution seems to be something like 640x480 which is very inconvenient. Is this a limitation of the Cloud Image missing basic graphics drivers or is it a config that can be changed?
